# How to move directory and all buffers within?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to reorganize a project and have several files from subdirectories opened in emacs. How can I move a directory and at the same time update all affected buffers of the files contained in the moved directory to point to the now moved files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dired`is your friend.  You can move (rename) directories and files and it will take care of your buffers.

Comment: Thank you. Why don't you provide a link to yourself, and your website (if any) on your profile? I'm an Emacs user myself and I am very glad to see much needed Emacs specialists here.